# Serializing/Deserializing buffered images

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I have a collection of buffered images that I want to serialize and then deserialize.
For example I have an arrayList full of buffered images which are iterated through and written to a
ObjectOutputStream

```
for (BufferedImages i : images{

ImageIO.write(i,"png",ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(output));

}
```

When I go to re-serialize the  images, I tried to use

```
 BufferedImage image =ImageIO.read(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(input));
```

but it only reads in one image.

Whats the correct way to re-serialize a collection of buffered images stored within the same serialized file?

Also once the images have been re-serialized they get redrawn to a JLabel,
How do I know which image is the correct one for each JLabel?

Comment: From what I know (which probably isn't much :P), I don't think what you are trying to do is possible.  I don't think PNG has a concept of sub images and even if it does, the way you are writing the images wouldn't produce the effect you're after.  Essentially, you're writing the "header/image data/footer" to the file.  `ImageIO` is reading the "header/image data/footer" and going, that's it, cause that how that image format works.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:Problem solved**

Ended up converting the buffered images to a byte array then stuck them in a hash map and used some hash codes as keys.
Then serialized the hash map.
All good.

Comment: Thanks in advance ..!!! Can you provide function or any API for that : converting the buffered images to a byte array then stuck them in a hash map and used some hash codes as keys. Then serialized the hash map...